# Sending email with lambda, aws ses and nodemailer not working

Tags: express, email, aws-lambda, nodemailer, amazon-ses

I am trying to use nodemailer to send email from my expressJS app hosted on aws lambda. It works locally but fail to send from lambda link.

I set my lambda to timeout in 2min.
Below is my code, kindly help:

```
const ses = new aws.SES({
apiVersion: "2010-12-01",
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
  signatureVersion: "v4",
  region: "us-east-2",
});

private generateNodemailerSESParams(to: string, subject: string, body: string) {
    try {
      const params = {
        from: {
          name: "clubzella",
          address: "hello@me.com"
        },
        to: [to],
        subject: subject,
        html: body,
        replyTo: "hello@me.com",
        attachments: [
          {
            filename: "test.pdf",
            path: path.join("src/email-templates/pdf1.pdf"),
            contentType: "application/pdf",
          },
         
        ],
      }
      return params
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
 
  }

async cNotification(email: string, data: { cta_url: string }) {

    try {
        // create Nodemailer SES transporter
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          SES: { ses, aws },
        });

        const sendMailPromise = util.promisify(transporter.sendMail).bind(transporter);

        const template = await this.getEmailTemplate("creative-contest", data);
        const params = this.generateNodemailerSESParams(email, template.title, template.body);

        await sendMailPromise(params);
        console.log('Email sent successfully');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    }
 }
```

i increase the lambda timeout but the error still persist. and cloudwatch is not displaying any error